# Call to undefined method MongoDB::find()

Tags: php, mongodb, database

Here's the code:

```
require_once("config.php");
class xy {
// List all the ingredients in a container
public function objectsInContainer($container) {
    global $mongo, $box;
    $hereUGo = $mongo->selectDB($box);
    $cursor = $hereUGo->find();
    return $cursor;
}
}
```

and in config.php, there's

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$box = $mongo->selectDB($box);
```

PHP is telling me `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method MongoDB::find()`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://puu.sh/9Ru58.png <- mongo is installed.

Comment: [Mongo class is depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongo.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MongoDB` has no method `find`. You have to select collection before searching.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongocollection.php